# Сортировка строк содержащие в себе числа

Tags: c#, сортировка

Строка имеет такую структуру: **100. Liubov_Prekrasno**. У каждой строки имеется числовой порядок(в начале строки) в формате текста. При записи в файл, данные строки сортирует как:
***10. name
11. name
...
2. name
20. name***  и тд.
Как исправить данную сортировку?

Код записи в файл:

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(PathToFolder);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            foreach (string filename in allfiles)
            {
               string _getFileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
                writer.WriteLine(_getFileNameWithoutExtension);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Простого способа нет. Штатная сортировка строк, как и положено - алфавитная, т.е. если первыми всегда будут строки с наименьшим кодом первого символа и т.д. как у вас и происходит. Извлекайте и  парсите номера в числа, сортируйте по числам. Иначе никак. Но если это имена файлов, то надо ли менять порядок сортировки? Они в проводнике ровно так же "неправильно" будут отсортированы

Comment: @rdorn как ни странно, но в папке они хранятся по числовому возрастанию, хотя сама сортировка идет по имени.

Comment: а можно как то считывать имена файлов без последующей сортировки? Или она автоматически происходит, было бы проще сохранять тот порядок каков он изначально.

Comment: Насчет автоматической сортировки я не знаю, не изучал этот вопрос. Но в эксплорере штатная сортировка по имени стандартная алфавитная, другую не видел, даже имена для подобных случаев специально задавал руками, чтобы был нужный порядок.

Comment: Проверил, действительно, Win10 сам распознает начальные цифры в именах, как-то не замечал раньше, ну что ж, значит вам придется таки делать то же самое руками, увы.